# Constraints don't work properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, constraints

I'm currently working on a project and I've created a custom view programmatically.

Here's the code I've written in the custom class:

```
class CodeView: UIView {

let codeTextView = UITextView()
let nameLabel = UILabel()
let dateLabel = UILabel()
let mainStackView = UIStackView()
let labelStackView = UIStackView()
let buttonStackView = UIStackView()
let lowerStackView = UIStackView()
let copyButton = UIButton()
let shareButton = UIButton()

let size = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 175)

public init(name: String?, date: String?, code: String) {

    if let name = name {
        nameLabel.text = name
    } else {
        nameLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    if let date = date {
        dateLabel.text = date
    } else {
        dateLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    codeTextView.text = code

    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 175))

    subview()
    setup()
    addingConstraints()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func setup() {

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    self.backgroundColor = .white

    codeTextView.textColor = .white
    codeTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 2/255, green: 11/255, blue: 57/255, alpha: 0.75)
    codeTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    codeTextView.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 15)

    nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 17)

    dateLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 17)

    copyButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Copy"), for: .normal)
    copyButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Copy Highlighted"), for: .highlighted)
    copyButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Copy Highlighted"), for: .selected)
    copyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(copyText), for: .touchUpInside)
    copyButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    copyButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    shareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Share"), for: .normal)
    shareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Share Highlighted"), for: .highlighted)
    shareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Share Highlighted"), for: .selected)
    shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareText), for: .touchUpInside)
    shareButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    shareButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


    mainStackView.axis = .vertical
    mainStackView.spacing = 10

    lowerStackView.axis = .horizontal
    lowerStackView.alignment = .center
    lowerStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally

    labelStackView.axis = .vertical

    buttonStackView.axis = .horizontal
    buttonStackView.alignment = .fill
    buttonStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    buttonStackView.spacing = 10

}

func addingConstraints() {

    //TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    codeTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mainStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    labelStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    copyButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    shareButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    let ViewWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 250)
    let ViewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 175)

    let MainStackViewCenterX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainStackView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let MainStackViewCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainStackView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let MainStackViewTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainStackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)
    let MainStackViewLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainStackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)
    let MainStackViewRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainStackView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)

    let CodeTextViewTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: codeTextView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainStackView, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let CodeTextViewLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: codeTextView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainStackView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let CodeTextViewRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: codeTextView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainStackView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let LowerStackViewBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: lowerStackView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainStackView, attribute: .bottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let LowerStackViewLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: lowerStackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainStackView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let LowerStackViewRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: lowerStackView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainStackView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let LabelStackViewCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelStackView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: lowerStackView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let LabelStackViewLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelStackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: lowerStackView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let ButtonStackViewCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonStackView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: lowerStackView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let ButtonStackViewRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonStackView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: lowerStackView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let CopyButtonWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: copyButton, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 28)
    let CopyButtonHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: copyButton, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 35)

    constraint.append(contentsOf: [ViewHeight, ViewWidth, MainStackViewCenterX, MainStackViewCenterY, MainStackViewTop, MainStackViewLeft, MainStackViewRight, CodeTextViewTop, CodeTextViewLeft, CodeTextViewRight, LowerStackViewBottom, LowerStackViewLeft, LowerStackViewRight, LabelStackViewCenterY, LabelStackViewLeft, ButtonStackViewCenterY, ButtonStackViewRight, CopyButtonWidth, CopyButtonHeight])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraint)

}

func subview() {

    self.addSubview(codeTextView)
    self.addSubview(nameLabel)
    self.addSubview(dateLabel)
    self.addSubview(copyButton)
    self.addSubview(shareButton)
    self.addSubview(mainStackView)
    self.addSubview(lowerStackView)
    self.addSubview(labelStackView)
    self.addSubview(buttonStackView)

    mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(codeTextView)
    mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(lowerStackView)

    lowerStackView.addArrangedSubview(labelStackView)
    lowerStackView.addArrangedSubview(buttonStackView)

    labelStackView.addArrangedSubview(nameLabel)
    labelStackView.addArrangedSubview(dateLabel)

    buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(copyButton)
    buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(shareButton)

}



func copyText() {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = codeTextView.text
}

func shareText() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Share?", message: "You probably don't want to share your code to everyone out there", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Share", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self.codeTextView.text], applicationActivities: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

And here's the code I wrote when I wanted to add the view to the app:

```
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
let codeView1 = CodeView(name: "Hello", date: "Today", code: "Bla bla bla")
let stackView = UIStackView()
var viewArray = [CodeView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewArray.append(codeView1)

    for i in viewArray {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(i)
    }

    contentView.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .center
    stackView.spacing = 20

    let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerX, centerY])

}
```

But after running the app it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65lPj.png)

Even though I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWbon.png)

I've added the exact same constraints in the code as I used in the storyboard.

Thank you very much, I really appreciate every kind of help

Comment: So, what I understand is you want your views have sharp corners instead of rounded corners. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

When coding constraints programmatically it is often best to use iOS 9 constraint anchors. Here is a snippet of the constraint anchors code I used for a user's cell in a chat app I developed programmatically.

```
    //ios 9 constraint anchors
    //need x,y,width,height anchors
    profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true

    //need x,y,width,height anchors
    timeLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    timeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
    timeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    timeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel!.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Obviously, the details of your constraints will differ from this example, but this should give you a template to experiment with in order to resolve your issue.